# Can a process write to both Error Stream and Input Stream?

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm creating a class which abstract process builder and makes it a bit more 'user-friendly' and i wonder if there's by any chance that a process can write to both input and error stream?

If so, Can you give me an example to a situation where it happens?

I want to determine whether to return the input buffer after checking error stream. Or i have to return both of them - That way if input stream contains useful information the user will be able to use it.

Comment: You can't write to an _input_ stream by definition. You probably mean stdout (and stderr). But yes, you can; stdout is System.out and stderr is System.err.

Comment: The process write to input stream, The user reads it. I don't see the problem.

Comment: No, you can't write to an `InputStream`; you write to an `OutputStream`, which will happen to be the other process' `InputStream`. You don't write to stdin, you write to stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the process can write to both the streams. Consider a situation where process needs to do some manipulation on input values sequentially, and the process prints OK to INPUT stream for every correct input, while the same Prints ERROR on ERROR stream if there is some logical input validation failure.
It will print ok on INPUT till it finds an error and ERROR on error stream.

Also usually the standard messages are sent to INPUT stream while warnings and errors go to ERROR stream.